# how to convert compiled url in normail form using python

Tags: python, json, url

I just used gogole api to search via python and used this script below

```
import urllib
import json as m_json
query = raw_input ( 'Query: ' )
query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
for result in results:

    url = result['url']   # was URL in the original and that threw a name error exception
    print (  url )
```

and after that I got result below :

```
Query: inurl:"readnews.php?id="
http://www.idmantv.az/readnews.php%3Fid%3D14999
http://www.kanda.com/readnews.php%3Fid%3D9
http://www.dcfever.com/news/readnews.php%3Fid%3D12573
http://www.thegrower.org/readnews.php%3Fid%3D6c0p5n0e8i6b
```

but I want this url in normal form like

```
http://www.idmantv.az/readnews.php?id=14999
```

How to do that with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) or [`urllib.unquote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus) to decode `%`-encoded string:

```
>>> urllib.unquote('http://www.idmantv.az/readnews.php%3Fid%3D14999')
'http://www.idmantv.az/readnews.php?id=14999'
```

Comment: Thanks and i also dont know how to increase number of result in upper script...do you have any idea?

Comment: @Nisarg, I don't know what do you mean the `number`?

Comment: As you can see in result of script above in my question....i use query and search for it and i got only 5 results...but how to get more result of my query

Comment: @Nisarg, According to the [Google Web Search API documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/reference), you can specify `rsz` with a number between 1 to 8. `'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?rsz=8&v=1.0&' + query`

Comment: @Nisarg, If you need more, you need to use loop with changing `start=` parameter.